# Issue with derived column transformation

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a column which is int and want to load the data based on condition for example say:

- if the value is 1 then load column with inserted
- value is 2 then load column with DELETED
- value is 3 then load column with UPDATED

But when I tried doing this I am getting the following error:

```
Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [1666]]: Attempt to parse the expression "[Copy of operation]== "1" ? "INSERTED"" failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.    
Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [1666]]: Cannot parse the expression "[Copy of operation]== "1" ? "INSERTED"". The expression was not valid, or there is an out-of-memory error.    
Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [1666]]: The expression "[Copy of operation]== "1" ? "INSERTED"" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Derived Column 1]" is not valid.    
Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [1666]]: Failed to set property "Expression" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Derived Column 1]".

 (Microsoft Visual Studio)

===================================

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

------------------------------
Program Location:
```

Comment: Is this your expression? `[Copy of operation]== "1" ? "INSERTED"`

Comment: yes Correct billinkc , this is change data capture column for operation performed such as __$operation that shows the operation type of the change, where 1 = delete, 2 = insert, 3 = update (before change), and 4 = update (after change). Instead of 1 i want the column data should look like Deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the issue is that you have an incomplete expression. The ternary operator `? :` has three parts to it  `(boolean expression) ? True bits : False bits`

```
[Copy of operation]== "1" ? "INSERTED" : [Copy of operation]== "2" ? "DELETED" : [Copy of operation]== "3"? "UPDATED" : "UNKNOWN"
```

This expression would read

- If the value of column copy of operation is 1, then return INSERTED
- - else If the value of column copy of operation is 2, then return DELETED
- - - else If the value of column copy of operation is 3, then return UPDATED
- - - - else return UNKNOWN

This does assume the data type of the column `Copy of operation` is a string. If it's a whole number, then you'd remove the double quotes around the values 1,2,3.

In the comments, you've indicated the __$operation indicates the value of the operation as `where 1 = delete, 2 = insert, 3 = update (before change), and 4 = update (after change)`

Continue with the above pattern along with changing out the differences (1 is delete in comment whereas 1 is inserted in question) to generate values.

A *different* approach is to use a tiny lookup table. You could even define it  with an inline query and use a Lookup Component to add your operation description into the data flow

```
SELECT
    OperationId
,   OperationName
FROM
(
    VALUES ('1', 'INSERTED')
    , ('2', 'DELETED')
   -- etc
)D(OperationId, OperationName);
```

Again, ensure you have your data types aligned